# Looping through multiple Regex extractor output

Tags: jmeter

Can you please tell me how to loop through the result of a Regex Post Processor that returns multiple values?

Example:

JSON Response message:

```
{
    "reply": {
        "code": "111",
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "customerID": [
            "222-a",
            "b-333",
            "44-4",
            "s-555",
            "666",
            "777",
            "88-8"
        ]
    }
}
```

Regx extractor helped me extract each individual component of the array:

```
links_1=222-a
links_2=b-333
```

I can use `some.url/${links_1}`.
Here is exactly what I am trying to achieve, but this does not seem to work.
Can you please help me?

Loop through the Regex extracted individual variable using a counter and append each one in another HTTP request sampler:

```
WhileController(${__javaScript(${C} < ${links_matchNr})}) 
HTTPSampler use ${__V(links_${C})}  
Counter (start=1,increment=1,maximum=${links_matchNr},referenceName=C)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller):

- input variable : links
- output variable : link for example

[image]

You can then use each value inside Controller through:

> ${link}

Answer (score 2):

I have created this tutorial, http://goo.gl/4cBno I hope its useful. To view the desktop sharing clearly, click on the full screen icon at the bottom right.

Comment: => "kPoint host is currently experiencing problem."

Comment: Hi @ShaiAlon can you please check again. Thanks for informing me.