# In JMeter how can I capture multiple (varying) values of a regular expression?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to parse a html page that can contain multiple (unspecified how many) links. 
Here an example (pseudo html):

```
<a href="../entrygroups/GROUPIDENTIFIER/3">edit</a>
[...]
<a href="../entrygroups/GROUPIDENTIFIER/7">edit</a>
[...]
<a href="../entrygroups/GROUPIDENTIFIER/12">edit</a>
[...]
<a href="../entrygroups/GROUPIDENTIFIER/16">edit</a>
```

I am basically just interested in the numbers `3`,`7`,`12`,`16` of the url.

Is there a way to put those values into some sort of array and loop over them (in a for each kind of way).

Is this possible and if so, how would I do this?
I looked at the regular expression extractor but it seems that that one can only assign a fixed set of groups to a fixed set of variables.

Comment: Check [Looping through multiple Regex extractor output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333680/looping-through-multiple-regex-extractor-output).

Comment: @user7294900 suggested `var response = SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString();` to access the response as string for further processing. Probably, it is also worth checking out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Extract the values using Regular Expression Extractor configured like:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `edit`
   - Regular Expression: `<a href="../entrygroups/GROUPIDENTIFIER/(.+?)">edit</a>`
   - Template: `$1`
   - Match No: `-1`

     [image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor]
2. Add [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) configured like:

   - Input variable prefix: `edit` (or whatever you used as the Regular Expression Extractor Reference Name)
   - Output variable prefix: again anything meaningful, i.e. `current_edit`

     [image]
3. Put the sampler(s) you need under the ForEach Controller
4. Refer the "GROUPIDENTIFIER" value as `${current_edit}` where required

   [image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor Looping Values]

See [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter) guide for another example of looping through all links found in the page with the Regular Expression Extractor and ForEach Controller.

Answer (score 2):

Actually RegEx extractor is able to do exactly what you want, if you specify **Match No. field with less than 0, e.g. -1**:

[image]

As a result, you will get *N* variables (using your input as example):

```
id_1=3
id_2=7
id_3=12
id_4=16
```

There also will be variable which has a count of matches:

```
id_matchNr=4
```